# Can't use mysqli with PHP on Windows from web-browser, but it works from command line

Tags: php, mysql, windows, apache, mysqli

In php.ini i have `extension_dir = "ext"` and `extension=php_mysqli.dll`

But when i use

```
$servername = "localhost";$username = "root";$password = "12345678";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
```

i got error:

> Class 'mysqli' not found

in `C:\php\ext` i have `php_mysqli.dll`.

Also running the same script from command line, `C:\Apache24\htdocs>php connection.php`, i have

> Connected successfully

I believe the problem is that when running from Apache, php **doesn't read php.ini**.

Comment: PHP from CLI is often different from what Apache is using. Create a php script with `phpinfo()` in it, load that in a browser. That'll help you figure out if MySQL is setup properly.

Comment: Also, the `getaddrinfo failed` error looks like your machine doesn't know where `MySQL57` is located. Can you ping `MySQL57` at CLI and get a response?

Comment: @jszobody hi, thank you for your answers, i have updated the question.

Comment: The phpinfo() output will tell you which ini file is being used

Answer (score 0):

It's appeared that for some reason when starting from apache php tries to read ini file from C:\Windows. Running info.php i got this line:

```
Configuration File (php.ini)                Path    C:\Windows
```

So, i just copied php.ini into C:\Windows and all works.